# Material ui load select option data list from server response but when select a option can not return selected value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use server response data to create my country and province select component.
first, the user chooses the country. Then we send a request to the server with the selected country id, get the country's provinces, and then re-render the province's select component with new data. finally, I submit the form but show the error **country is a required field**.
I'm adding to the country select component **(onChange)** and saving the selected country id in the state but it does not solve this issue.
below is my select option component code:

```
<RHFSelect value={selects.country} name="country" label="Country" placeholder="Country" onChange={(e) => handleCountrySelect(e.target.value)}>
    <option value="" />
    {countries.map((option) => (
       <option key={option.id} value={option.id}>
           {option.name}
       </option>
    ))}
</RHFSelect>
```

my state

```
const [selects, setSelects] = useState({
    country: undefined,
    province: undefined
});
```

on change handler function

```
const handleCountrySelect = (id) => {
    setSelects((props) => ({ ...props, country: id }));
    getProvince(id);
};
```

I'm using **minimal dashboard** source code and it's for handling the form using **react-hook-form**

```
const methods = useForm({
   resolver: yupResolver(UpdateUserSchema),
   defaultValues,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use react-select if possible. https://react-select.com/home
and here is the example how to use

```
<Select closeMenuOnSelect={false}
 isMulti as="select"
 options={options} 
 value={options.filter(obj => 
 selectedValue.includes(obj.value))} // set selected values
 onChange={handleChange}/>
```

```
const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedValue(Array.isArray(e) ? e.map(x => x.value) : []);
  }

console.log(selectedValue)
```